# Is this ok for using EntityFramework context

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, static

In my DAL, I'm currently using this in a base class:

```
protected static MyCMSEntities MyCMSDb
{
    get { return new MyCMSEntities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCMSEntities"].ConnectionString); }
}
```

and calling like this from a subclass:

```
public static bool Add(ContentFAQ newContent)
{
    MyCMSEntities db = MyCMSDb;
    newContent.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
    newContent.OwnerUserId = LoginManager.CurrentUser.Id;
    db.ContentFAQ.AddObject(newContent);
    return db.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

I understand the method to get the context is static, but as it creates a new intance of the context, this is not static, i.e. it is new for each call to the Add method.

Am I correct and more importantly, ok for a web application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in using a new context for every web call - but why this obfuscation? I would recommend removing this indirection with the static property (makes the code harder to understand) and also using a `using` block since the context is disposable:

```
public static bool Add(ContentFAQ newContent)
{
    using(var db = new MyCMSEntities())
    {
      newContent.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
      newContent.OwnerUserId = LoginManager.CurrentUser.Id;
      db.ContentFAQ.AddObject(newContent);
      return db.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
}
```

Also the default constructor of the context should use the default connection string, which is the right one if you didn't change it in your configuration (otherwise just add it back in).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The question was not why I was doing it this way.  It was asking whether it was reasonable and correct in my assumptions to do it that way.

Comment: @Dave yes- you can do it that way,  just make sure you dispose the context after you are done, preferably with a `using` block.

Comment: I was under the impression that it would be disposed of by the gc after the call to Add had finished.  Is that wrong?

Comment: @Dave: it will *eventually* get disposed, its best practice though to release unneeded resources as soon as possible, hence you should call `Dispose()` which the using block does for you.

Comment: @Dave: GC behavior is undeterministic - you should never count on time the GC release the resources. That is the whole point of IDisposable. Once a class implements `IDisposable` you should **always** handle Dispose method to explicitly release resources.